# How can I get the whole row after inserted into MySQL in Python

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have a table `session` which looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS session (
    token       CHAR(16),
    channel     VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    user        VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    is_host     BOOLEAN         NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    create_at   TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    last_active TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (token),
    FOREIGN KEY (user)          REFERENCES user(username),
    UNIQUE KEY (channel, user)
);
```

Now I would like to insert a row by API using FLASK by query

```
INSERT INTO session (token, channel, user) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
```

How could I get the auto inserted datetime `create_at` after insertion?

Comment: If you are using [MariaDB-10.5+](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/) there is `INSERT ... RETURNING`

Comment: Then how to capture the return in flask?

Comment: `INSERT INTO session (token, channel, user) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) RETURNING created_at` and for Flask, treat the `INSERT` statement as if it was `SELECT created_at FROM session`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get the idea that a select query is unavoidable.

Comment: no, treat the insert query as though it will return values to the cursor. Select isn't needed.